# AttributeError when setting coordinate system with set_crs() in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, geodataframe

I'm trying to set the coordinate reference system for a `GeoDataFrame` using the following code:

```py
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.geometry import Point

d = {'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'geometry': [Point(1, 2), Point(2, 1)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d)

gdf = gdf.set_crs('epsg:3857')
```

However, when running `gdf.set_crs('epsg:3857')`, I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\my_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5487, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_crs'
```

I looked inside `geodataframe.py` and indeed there is no object called `set_crs`. How do I get the `set_crs` object in here? FYI I installed GeoPandas from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

---

I tried copying the `set_crs` object (found here: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/528abfc6fe4a501ebffa7aa16cb05a5aa656c8dd/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L1116) into `geodataframe.py`, but it did not solve the issue. Instead I received more errors.

Comment: Try just using the integer 3857. See https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html# . Ie gdf = gdf.set_crs(3857, allow_override=True). Also, I would definitely install the package from source rather than someone's unofficial release if you're having an issue with a core attribute

Comment: The `set_crs` method was [added in geopandas 0.8.0](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/changelog.html#version-0-8-0-june-24-2020).  There's two versions on lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs, did you install the old 0.6.2 version instead of 0.10.2?

Comment: @user2856 is correct! In my case this `gdf.set_crs('epsg:3857')` works without problems, I am on GeoPandas 0.10.2.

Comment: Why not add the CRS when you invoke the constructor?:
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:3857")